# Wordpress: Create custom value in wp_get_archives dropdown

Tags: wordpress, filter, dropdown

I'm having a Wordpress related question. Right now I'm getting my yearly based custom-post-type archive like this:

```
$args = array ( 
   'type' => 'yearly',
   'post_type'    => 'project',
   'format' => 'custom',
   'before' => '<li value="2016" data-filter-value=".classof2016">',
   'after' => '</li>'
);

wp_get_archives($args);
```

As you can see, I’m creating a value and a data filter value that should be related to the year. The result should look like this:

```
<li value="2016" data-filter-value=".classof2016">2016</li>
<li value="2015" data-filter-value=".classof2015">2015</li>
<li value="2014" data-filter-value=".classof2014">2014</li>
```

How can I achive this solution? Anybody could help?

Thanks in advance!
Cara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[wp_get_archives()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives) uses [get_archives_link()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_archives_link) and here is a filter hook than we can use.

[Sourcecode](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1574) is the best documentation.

Try this (in your `functions.php`):

```
add_filter( 'get_archives_link', function( $link_html, $url, $text, $format, $before, $after ) {

    if ( 'custom' == $format ) {
        $link_html = "\t<li value=\"". esc_attr( $text ) ."\" data-filter-value=\".classof". esc_attr( $text ) ."\">$before<a href='$url'>$text</a>$after</li>\n";
    }

    return $link_html;

}, 10, 6 );
```

But by the way: A `value` attribute in `li` element is not valid HTML.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, I used your code. Instead of `return $output;` I used `return $link_html;` then it worked. Is it right, like that? And btw: I deleted the `value` attribute. Thanks for the hint!